# Git Rebase in jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, rebase

In Jenkins I have a requirement that before applying `git merge`, I need to perform a `git rebase`. Now for `git merge`, I am using Jenkins git branch merge option, but for `git rebase`, I don't find such functionality in Jenkins. So, do I need to write script for this or is there any option in Jenkins which I can apply to do `git rebase` before `git merge`?

Comment: Rebasing can be much more complicated than merging.  In the case of merging, a repo (e.g. GitHub) can sort of "know" that a merge will complete without conflicts.  In the case of a rebase operation, it is not that simple.  This is my guess as to why Jenkins doesn't support this option (but maybe it does).

Comment: By "_Jenkins git branch merge option_" do you mean _SCM_ → _Git_ → _Additional Behaviours_ → _Merge before build_ in your project's config? The cmd  for the script would be [`git pull --rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt--r).